# Issue accessing hash inside of an array with Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, api, hash, httparty

I have set out on the task of learning ruby/rails and accessing API's with Ruby. I have a quick question:

I am making a GET request which returns JSON. Once I get that JSON back I need to be able to organize it so I can pull out what I want...However, the JSON comes back as an array with a hash inside. So, response.body returns what you see below. Response[0] gives me all of the JSON that makes up my request and leaves off the "13". Response[1] gives me just 13. How can I get, for example, the id for each survey without all of the excess JSON?

> {
>     "surveys": [
>       {
>         "status": "live",
>         "responses": 2,
>         "creator": "Service Organizer",
>         "updated_at": "2013-07-10T22:16:23+00:00",
>         "deploy_uri": "link",
>         "responses_url": "link",
>         "id": 221584,
>         "name": "Test Email",
>         "created_at": "2013-07-10T19:54:32+00:00",
>         "uri": "link",
>         "report_url": "link",
>         "edit_url": "link"
>       },
>       {
>         "status": "live",
>         "responses": 2,
>         "creator": "Service Organizer",
>         "updated_at": "2013-07-10T22:16:23+00:00",
>         "deploy_uri": "link",
>         "responses_url": "link",
>         "id": 221584,
>         "name": "Test Email",
>         "created_at": "2013-07-10T19:54:32+00:00",
>         "uri": "link",
>         "report_url": "link",
>         "edit_url": "link"
>       }
>     ],
>     "total": 13
>   }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, to collect the ids:

```
survey_ids = response.body["surveys"].map { |s| s["id"] }
```

For this to work, you have to convert the JSON string to Ruby format with `JSON.parse` per Dan Singerman's comment.

Comment: That makes sense, but I'm getting the following error:

undefined method `map' for "surveys":String (NoMethodError)

Any ideas?

Comment: The hash you gave actually isn't valid Ruby hash syntax. I updated my response accordingly.

Comment: Parse your JSON to a ruby hash first with JSON.parse(response.body)

Comment: Indeed. I am using the HTTParty gem and was under the understanding that the JSON was already ready to rock when I got it. I used JSON.parse() and the code above worked fine. Thanks for the help!